# readdir/File::Find::Rule is not reading a subdirectory and its contents in perl

Tags: linux, perl, suse

I have tried 3 different ways to read contents of a folder and none of them are able to identify a subdirectory in a setup.

Strange part is, when i recreate the folder structure locally , the sub-directory is identified and i get the file i am looking for with all the 3 solutions.

This sub directory is created on the fly along with other files in the folder in the setup. Every time i am able to read all the files which are created but not the sub directory and its contents.

I tried below solutions.

Solution 1:

```
use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = '.';
my @subdirs = File::Find::Rule->directory->in($dir);
foreach (@subdirs) {
  print "Dir --> $_ \n";
}

my @list = ("*.txt", "*.rex");
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name(@list)->in(@subdirs);

foreach (@files) {
  print "File --> $_ \n";
}
```

--> It does not list the sub directory. The sub-directory contains the file i am looking for. So i am not getting the files.

Variant of solution 1, which directly looks in the folder.

```
my $dir = getcwd();
my @types = ("*.txt","*.rex");
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name(@types)->in("$dir");

print join("\n", @files);
```

This also does not print the files, as i see it does not check the sub directory which has the files.

Solution 2:

```
my $cwd = getcwd();

sub find_rex {
    my $f = $File::Find::name;

    if ($f =~ /rex$/){
     print "$f \n";
    }
}

find (\&find_rex, $cwd);
```

Solution 3:

```
my @dirlist = '.'; # current dir, or command line arguments
foreach (@dirlist) { &check_dir($_); }
exit 0;

sub check_dir {
  my $dir=shift;
  print "Dir to search --> $dir \n";

  warn "cannot traverse directory $dir\n"
    unless (opendir D,$dir);
  my @files = map {$dir.'/'.$_} grep {!m/^\.{1,2}$/} readdir D;
  closedir D;


  foreach (@files) {
    if (-d $_) { 
                 &check_dir($_);
    }
    elsif (-f $_) { 
                   if ($_ =~ /\.rex$/ ){
                     print "Filename --> $_ \n";
                  }
    }
}
```

}

All these solutions worked locally for me to get the contents of the sub directory. I ensured the sub-directory had the same permissions locally also to test my code.The solutions work locally but it does not work in the actual setup.

I have run out of ideas. I am able to see the sub folder and the files in it i need when i list them in linux. I have tried the glob as well, but it also does not work.

More details: OS: Suse Linux , Bash/TCSH shell

Can anyone suggest something that i can try. I am not sure whether its a readdir problem or something else.

Has anyone faced this type of strange problem. What could i be doing wrong?
Please do suggest what i can do?

The sub folder which does not get recognized is something like this 
2018-07-29T22.57.52

This folder contains the files i am looking for and Perl Modules Find and readdir does not seems to be checking this.

Please do let me know if i need to rephrase my question.

Comment: Is your directory a symlink? Does `->extras({ follow => 1 })` help?

Comment: Its not a symlink, i checked that. Its a normal directory. I will try with the option you mentioned.

Comment: It did not work. I tried with my @files = File::Find::Rule->extras({ follow => 1 })->file()->name(@types)->in("$dir");

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but did you check that the subdirectory is indeed "_created on the fly_" ?

Comment: yes, it is created on the fly. I have checked it.

Comment: To confirm my understanding: When you create that directory (and files in it) by hand then the code you have works; But when it is created by the program ("_on the fly_") ... then it doesn't work?  Did you test with the exact same program -- once you make things by hand and run it and then you (delete that and) run it?

Comment: Yes, I have simply copied the directory and its contents  which are created on the fly to my local disk and used the same code snippet which i wrote in a local script. Here it works. But it doesn't work in the setup where the same code gets called after the directory and its content are created. I have double checked every line and the $dir i pass in both cases to confirm that it is correct. As i did a print of all files present in that $dir and observe it prints all files except the sub-directory. i checked manually in the $dir to see if the sub-directory was not present but it is present.

Comment: It seems that your "_actual setup_" ends up with wrong name(s), for some reason (since the directory is there as you say). Try to check right before the search, `if (not -d $subdir) { ... }` where `$subdir` is composed with other variables that you use (perhaps `$dir/sub_dir_name` or such)?  You'd have to show/tell us about your "_actual setup_" for more than (better) guesses.

Comment: I think you need to show the code that creates and populates the missing directory as well.

Comment: It's not the source of your problem, but don't use ampersands `&` to call subroutines. Just `check_dir($_)` is correct.

Comment: This is a comment on your code style. It's better practice to use a lexical variable for a directory handle. So your lines for reading in the directory would better be written:-
 warn "cannot traverse directory $dir\n"
     unless (opendir my $D,$dir);
 my @files = map {$dir.'/'.$_} grep {!m/^\.{1,2}$/} readdir $D;
 closedir $D;

Comment: Use `opendir` and `readdir` to read the directory and see what error you get.

Comment: Borodin: Thank you for the input. I am currently create a local snippet of code for replicating the issue. I will use your incorporate you suggestion in my code and come back with the code.
JDNI: Thank you. I will modify accordingly.
ikegami : Thank you. Yes, i am doing the same . currently trying to debug why readir doesn't read this.